# Understanding relation between different versions of relative pronouns

Tags: relative-clause, definite-article

In [this article](https://yourdailygerman.com/wo-compounds-worauf-woraus-wovon-meaning-german/) it is explained how wo-words can be used as relative pronouns but when reading it I am a bit confused due to the previous knowledge I have with definite article being used relative pronouns (with alternate conjugations of course). How do these things go with each other? One particular question which sticks out is how do I know if I should wo-word or definite article as relative pronoun?

wo-words: worauf, woran, womit, ...

An example sentence:

> Das ist das einzige, woran ich mich erinnern kann.

Comment: The words used as relative pronouns are not the same as definite articles. For one thing they are declined differently; compare *Du solltest den Leuten kein Geld geben.* and *Wer sind die Leute, denen du kein Geld geben solltest?* (Based on an example [here](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Wort/Pronomen/FRegeln-P/RelInter/RelPron-der-die-das.xml?lang=de).)

Comment: When reading the linked article, I can't really understand the "wierdness" of "wo-"words that's opinionated there - the writer apparently wasn't aware that English has (or, used to have) an absolute parallel construct - even a literal translate - with the pair of "wherefore/therefore" (which hasn't got anything to do with location as well).

Comment: I (German native speaker, very interested in German language) have never heard the term *"wo-word"* (or *"Wo-Wort"*) before. I had to google for it. So that not everyone else has to search for it, I've put an explanatory line at the end of the post.

Comment: I am particularly interested in wo-word as relative pronoun... could you please help me?

Comment: https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/368 has an overview of elements that can introduce relative clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have misunderstood something. Your question makes no sense because there is no definite article or relative pronouin that begins with *"wo-"* or is the part after *"wo-"* in an existing wo-word.

### Definite articles

D definite article is a word that accompanies a noun, indicates it's grammatical gender (at least in languages where nouns have genders) and marks the nous as being not just any thing but exactly this thing. (It indicates the nouns definiteness.)

German has exactly 6 definite articles:

- **der** (the)
  **Der** Mann schläft. **The** man is sleeping.
- **die** (the)
  **Die** Frau schläft. **The** woman is sleeping.
- **das** (the)
  **Das** Kind schläft. **The** child is sleeping.
- **des** (the)
  Das Kleid **des** Kindes ist rot. The dress of **the** child is red.
- **dem** (the)
  Das Kleid gehört **dem** Kind. The dress belongs to **the* child.
- **den** (the)
  Das Kind sieht **den** Mann. The child sees **the** man.

There are no other words in German that are definite articles. None of these words begins with *"wo-".* So, non of them is a wo-word. Also none of these 6 words is the part after *"wo-"* of any existing wo-word.

---

### Relative pronouns

A relative pronoun is a word that initiates a relative clause.

German has exactly 20 relative pronouns. You can arrange them in 3 groups:

Group 1:

- **der**
  Der Mann, **der** dort saß, lächelte. - The man **who** sat there smiled.
- **die**
  Die Frau, **die** dort saß, lächelte. - The woman **who** sat there smiled.
- **das**
  Das Kind, **das** dort saß, lächelte. - The child **who** sat there smiled.
- **dem**
  Der Mann, **dem** ich zuhörte, lächelte. - The man **who** who I was listening to smiled.
- **den**
  Der Mann, **den** ich sah, lächelte. - The man **who** who saw smiled.
- **denen**
  Die Männer, **denen** ich zuhörte, lächelten. - The men **who** who I was listening to smiled.
- **deren**
  Die Frau, **deren** Hund bellte, lächelte. - The woman **whose** dog was barking smiled.
- **dessen**
  Der Mann, **dessen** Hund bellte, lächelte. - The woman **whose** dog was barking smiled.
- **derer** (rare)
  Er hatte einige Zaubersprüche, **derer** er sich nicht mehr ganz entsinnen konnte. - He had some spells **that** he couldn't quite remember.

Group 2:

- **welcher**
  Der Mann, **welcher** dort saß, lächelte. - The man **who** sat there smiled.
- **welche**
  Die Frau, **welche** dort saß, lächelte. - The woman **who** sat there smiled.
- **welches**
  Das Kind, **welches** dort saß, lächelte. - The child **who** sat there smiled.
- **welchem**
  Der Mann, **welchem** ich zuhörte, lächelte. - The man **who** who I was listening to smiled.
- **welchen**
  Der Mann, **welchen** ich sah, lächelte. - The man **who** who saw smiled.

Group 3:

- **wer** (animate: humans, animals, androids, etc.)
  **Wer** will, kann gehen. - **Whoever** wants to can go.
- **was** (inanimate: anything else but humans animals etc.)
  Ich mache, **was** ich will. - I do **what** I want.
- **wessen** (animate)
  **Wessen** Brot ich esse, dessen Lied singe ich. - **Whose** bread I eat, whose song I sing.
- **wes** (old fashioned, animate)
  **Wes** Brot ich ess', des Lied ich sing'. - **Whose** bread I eat, whose song I sing.
- **wen** (animate)
  **Wen** man auch fragt, alle sagen dasselbe. - **Whoever** you ask, they all say the same thing.
- **wem** (animate)
  Ich sage das, **wem** ich will. - I'll say this to **whomever** I want.

This list of relative pronouns is complete. No other German word is a relative pronoun. And again: None of them starts with *"wo-"* or ist the part after *"wo-"* in a wo-word.

---

### wo-words

There is no category named *wo-word* or *Wo-Wort* in German grammar. (I had to google for this term when I read this question.) I found these 16 word that match the definition given in the article linked in the question:

> wobei, wodurch, woher, wohin, womit, wonach, woran, worauf, woraus, worein, worin, worum, worüber, wovon, wovor, wozu

All these words are adverbs. (Some of them are pronominal adverbs, some can be used as interrogative adverbs, but they are all adverbs.) There are many more adverbs, most of them do not start with *"wo-":* hier, draußen, bergauf, heute, darum, deshalb, ...

There is nothing special about adverbs that start with *"wo-"* (at least not more special than verbs starting with *"ab-"* or any other prefix) and there is no relation between these adverbs and any articles or pronouns.

Comment: I thought group 2 came under wo words. Could you please explain the difference between group 2 and group 1s usage? That js what js making me going crazy

Comment: @Buraian: I added a section about *wo-words.* About the usage of welch*: Maybe this question can help you: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34045/use-of-den-and-der/34047#34047 - the point is: You can freely interchange *der* and *welcher* if there exists a *welch*-word, like I did in the examples that I gave in this answer.

Comment: I really don't know what kind of person would downvote an answer like this but thank you so much!!!

Comment: One question, does there not always exist a welch word

Comment: @Buraian: In genitive case there is no masculine or neuter welch-word. So for *»Der Mann, **dessen** Hund bellte, lächelte.«* you must use *dessen*. Here no welch-word exists. For feminine nouns this is possible but rare and sounds very oldfashioned (*»Die Frau, **welcher** Hund bellte, lächelte.«*). So in genitive case you better use *deren* (*»Die Frau, **deren** Hund bellte, lächelte.«*). Plural goes - like often - with feminine: *»Die Leute, **welcher** Hunde bellten, lächelten.«* is possible but very rare, so *deren* fits much better:  *»Die Leute, **deren** Hunde bellten, lächelten.«* ..

Comment: ... In both cases (genitive case for feminine and plural) also *derer* is possible: »Die Frau, **derer** Hund bellte, lächelte.« »Die Leute, **derer** Hunde bellten, lächelten.« In these situations *derer* is better than *welcher,* but the version you should prefer is *deren*. See also: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativpronomen

Comment: Could you please share a reference other than wiki as well? Eevrytime I search welch words on Internet I find something related to questions rather than relative pronouns